# How to model from photo referance?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I have a photo that I really make into a 3d model but I have no idea how to make it into a  3d model. Can someone provide a step by step on how to make this house into a 3d model?  What mesh do I start with?
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is too broad to be answerable without requiring an extensive tutorial or description. You should show efforts towards reaching your goal, describing what you have tried and why it failed, so we don't risk recommending something you already know. The scope should also focus on a particular step you encountered an issue with. Describing the whole procedure from start to finish would be too lengthy to explain, and is beyond the goal of this site. If you could [edit] your post to focus on where you are stuck we can vote to reopen it.

Comment: as Duarte says, your question is too broad, you should follow some tutorials, like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKk3XVan9qY ... or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmBMcYVW9x8 ... etc...

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is start with a cube, but really, I think you're asking how to model. There are a lot of great tutorials on YouTube. Grant Abbitt has a great series on beginning modeling. You should start here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7MRonzqYJgw&list=PLn3ukorJv4vs_eSJUQPxBRaDS8PrVmIri. But there are many ways to learn Blender, and many excellent tutorials (Blender Guru's Doughnut series, etc.). Good luck, and don't get discouraged.